# Need to get specific node by name using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have 4 urls..now i need the sleeves details for the urls..the sleeves detail change position and hence the node where it is stored also changes...for the first url the sleeve is at 2nd position and for the other three urls sleeve is at 3rd position..I need the output as below...

```
URLS                                                                                                        Sleeves
http://www.jabong.com/belle-fille-Green-Solid-Winter-Jacket-1310755.html?pos=5&cid=BE797WA44OZRINDFAS   Full Sleeves
http://www.jabong.com/oxolloxo-Off-White-Solid-Reversible-Blazer-2687327.html?pos=8&cid=OX344WA72XITINDFAS  Long Sleeve
http://www.jabong.com/oxolloxo-Multicoloured-Checked-Blazer-2784283.html?pos=16&cid=OX344WA16KTVINDFAS  3/4th Sleeves
http://www.jabong.com/mirika-Blue-Embellished-WINTER-JACKET-2754538.html?pos=19&cid=MI137WA61STUINDFAS  Sleeveless
```

Below is my part of the code:

```
for 1st url : soup.find_all("span", {"class":"product-info-left"})[1].next_sibling.text

for 2nd to 4th url : soup.find_all("span", {"class":"product-info-left"})[2].next_sibling.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find("span", text="Sleeves").next_sibling.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find only those strings which are containing `'Sleeve'`.

```
def check(text):
    return type(text) != type(None) and text.find('Sleeve') > -1

sleeves = soup.find_all(string=check)
print(sleeves[1])
```

**Output**

```
Full Sleeves
Long Sleeve
3/4th Sleeves
Sleeveless
```

To learn filtering using function check this [link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).